# Jest test for typeerror is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am testing the following function with Jest:

```
function add(number1, number2) {
    if (number1 === undefined || typeof number1 !== 'number' || number2 === undefined || typeof number2 !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('problem');
    }
    return number1 + number2;
  }
```

The test is as follows:

```
test('Test 5', () => {
  expect(calculate.add('one', -10)).toThrow();
});
```

I then get this result after running the test.
[image]
I have no idea what I'm getting wrong here as my other tests which do not look for errors seem to be running fine, thus ruling out any import issues.

Comment: The error is thrown _before_ `expect` gets called. Read the docs - you need to pass a _function_ to defer execution: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [.toThrow()](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror) docs:

> Note: You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.

```js
expect(() => calculate.add('one', -10)).toThrow();
```